# The remote server returned an error: (421) -Getting this error when trying to access Office 365 mailbox

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, exchangewebservices

I have created a standalone netbeans java 8.0 application which uses EWS to connect to Office 365 mailbox. I have registered the same in the Azure Directory.
Currently using basic authentication ,I can download the mails from the Office 365 mailbox and check the attachements. But the momment i change it to xoauth method using access token i get above mentioned error (The remote server returned an error: (421)). Can you please help me out with this.
I have used below code.

```
IClientCredential credential = ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(CLIENT_SECRET);
            ConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplication
                    .builder(PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID, credential)
                    .authority(AUTHORITY)
                    .build();
 
Set<String> scopes = new HashSet<String>();
scopes.add("api://"+PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID"/.default");

 ClientCredentialParameters clientCredentialParameters = ClientCredentialParameters.builder(scopes).build();
             CompletableFuture<IAuthenticationResult> future = app.acquireToken(clientCredentialParameters);

 ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
 service.setUrl(new URI("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/exchange.asmx"));

 BearerAccessToken bat = new BearerAccessToken(future.get().accessToken());
ExchangeCredentials credentials = new TokenCredentials(bat.getValue());
EnumSet<TraceFlags> es = EnumSet.of(TraceFlags.EwsRequest, TraceFlags.EwsRequestHttpHeaders, TraceFlags.EwsResponse, TraceFlags.EwsResponseHttpHeaders,TraceFlags.DebugMessage);

 service.setCredentials(credentials);
 service.setTraceEnabled(true);
 service.setTraceFlags(es);

FindItemsResults findResults = service.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, itemview);
```

The last last step above give me the error.
I am new to this msal4j and EWS . Can you please help me out with this. I need to access a office 365 mailbox for example: abc@abc.biz

Answer (score 0):

If your using Service principal authentication (client credentials flow) then you also need to use Impersonation in EWS. So in your code you need something like

```
service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "abc@abc.biz");
```

Comment: Even after  adding above step , I am getting the same error.

Comment: 421 sounds like you have a network path issue so your request aren't making it to the Office365 so i would start just checking the path out (eg proxy servers etc)

Comment: This is real strange,,, If i give the password and use basic authentication then code works perfectly fine , but with access token it gives above error. If there was any network path related issue then the basic authentication flow should also fail right ?

Comment: either way its just a header in the request if the header is invalid you should get a 401 not a 421. A few things to try is try using the EWSEditor (the oauth option) just to test outside of your code https://github.com/dseph/EwsEditor/releases, the other thing would be to include the X-AnchorMailbox header eg service.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", targetSmtp); which will help with routing which may cause the 421 (but I've never seen that happen)

Comment: I have already included  the X-AnchorMailbox header. once this is done the 421 error has gone but now I am getting below error  "microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. An internal server error occurred. The operation failed." at this step :   FindFoldersResults findResults = service.findFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, folderview);

Comment: Are you still including the impersonation header ? what does you trace request look like?

Comment: microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.
 at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.SimpleServiceRequestBase.internalExecute(SimpleServiceRequestBase.java:74)
 at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.MultiResponseServiceRequest.execute(MultiResponseServiceRequest.java:158)

Comment: You've got http tracing enabled so what does the actual request going to the server look like

Answer (score 0):

EWS Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"><soap:Header xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010"></t:RequestServerVersion><t:ExchangeImpersonation><t:ConnectingSID><t:SmtpAddress>lsrtestingmbx01@neustar.biz</t:SmtpAddress></t:ConnectingSID></t:ExchangeImpersonation>&lt;wsa:Action soap:mustUnderstand='1'&gt;http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages/FindFolder&lt;/wsa:Action&gt;&lt;wsa:ReplyTo&gt;&lt;wsa:Address&gt;http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous&lt;/wsa:Address&gt;&lt;/wsa:ReplyTo&gt;&lt;wsa:To soap:mustUnderstand='1'&gt;https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx/wssecurity&lt;/wsa:To&gt;&lt;wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand='1'&gt;  nulleyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6InUwc05rV2hLTjNrdXo0UzFCWWtKQzFwckxZYlZ6QWxFTHNXWEloSTBFSkkiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Im5PbzNaRHJPRFhFSzFqS1doWHNsSFJfS1hFZyIsImtpZCI6Im5PbzNaRHJPRFhFSzFqS1doWHNsSFJfS1hFZyJ9.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.G35t65b5V0MBXhPpXADZNKZlnqGpeb5T7iu4jIAnciCchkYhfurlSztTwf_M1DT9QgVymI9fy1RtLwZ5Xr4qXRtIAywFW9N5HJHzhC05-4612ORkVF7G7X0f_NIg057k1dED2qO-xpXU52dYgZFWa83t5g46Nj_DaB8Yci2vvwu4CjLhZwQ3cQOCkYK2Bq2AFJNQ68e50tOx6nueZruIlIMADoWBXGpLF9L1aVibTg7dloumtyuh1IoTtWzZrCEMt6tW_-H5YxFccB04NzCpi7Tg1Ju1PDeqLNRx17-EE1LZM0wisqke4FOf_OLjmzm3lxJCvLc-jLGts_ZFDrgP4g&lt;/wsse:Security&gt;</soap:Header><soap:Body><m:FindFolder Traversal="Shallow"><m:FolderShape><t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape></m:FolderShape><m:IndexedPageFolderView MaxEntriesReturned="10" Offset="0" BasePoint="Beginning"></m:IndexedPageFolderView><m:ParentFolderIds><t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="inbox"></t:DistinguishedFolderId></m:ParentFolderIds></m:FindFolder></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am now getting below HTTP Header:
TRACE FLAG:EwsResponseHttpHeaders  VALUE:
401 null
X-Proxy-BackendServerStatus : 401
Server : Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Proxy-RoutingCorrectness : 1
WWW-Authenticate : Bearer client_id="00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000", trusted_issuers="00000001-0000-0000-c000-000000000000@*", token_types="app_asserted_user_v1 service_asserted_app_v1", authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize", **error="invalid_token",Basic Realm=""**
X-CalculatedBETarget : DM5PR1701MB1900.NAMPRD17.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
request-id : e64c6048-3827-e102-de0b-8e25f54c83c4
X-RUM-Validated : 1
X-FEProxyInfo : DM5PR17CA0062.NAMPRD17.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
Date : Mon, 28 Jun 2021 06:09:17 GMT
**x-ms-diagnostics : 2000008;reason="The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood.";error_category="invalid_grant"**
X-CalculatedFETarget : DM5PR17CU003.internal.outlook.com
X-BEServer : DM5PR1701MB1900
X-BackEndHttpStatus : 401
X-DiagInfo : DM5PR1701MB1900
Set-Cookie : exchangecookie=4b4d794dbe6c41a89fba4e5b34fb9d66; expires=Tue, 28-Jun-2022 06:09:18 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
X-BeSku : Gen9
X-FEServer : BL0PR02CA0136
Content-Length : 0
X-Powered-By : ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
service.setCredentials(credentials);
```

Try this:

```
service.getHttpHeaders().put("Authorization", "Bearer " + bat.getValue());
```